# Is it possible to replace Shimano stem shifter SL-S441 Indexed SIS with new metal knobs but keep the clamp?

Tags: shimano, shifter, vintage

I have a Stem Shimano SIS SL-S441 (2x6) shifter on my bicycle. I want to restore the bicycle, take it apart, repaint it. I'm very much a noob and I've searched for 6 hours and unable to

1. find the answer to my question so here I am
2. unable to find another stem indexed shifter that's metal that I could swap out

What are my options? Could I keep the clamp on mine but just buy a shimano indexed shifter with the same speeds that's used on a downtube and just replace that onto my stem clamp (I've seen the clamp sold separately).

Is there a clamp + metal shifter index combo I could purchase to make this happen?

thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Just one tip: 6, 7, 8 and 9 speed shifters all use the same pull ratio. You could try widening your search. You’ll have some unused gear steps but that’s mostly a “cosmetic” issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I figured that much. But it was mostly replacing the handles I circled in red. Shimano didn't seem to make indexed metal knob quill stem shifters. I have only found downtube ones and wanted to know if I could swap the knobs of downtube onto the clamp of the quill stem and what I should be looking out for for compatibility.

Comment: If you are going to buy a component to take it apart and adapt to your shifter, why not buy a replacement SL-S441 and install that? they seem to be available to purchase

Comment: I ended up buying a Bianchi 1985 vintage that came with Shimano 600 on it, downtube shifters. it's a 6 speed freewheel, from what I understood, I could switch the derailleur to an SIS, get a 6 speed SIS shifter and I'm golden! Can anyone confirm if it's that simple?

Comment: @Jessie-James : The base or mounting poing for standard lever shifters, either for downtube or on a collar for quill-stem shifters is always a square with a threaded cylinder on top.

Comment: @Jessie-James I understand that these are the shifting levers of the bike in your other question. Doesn't the wire handle on the right have two defined position. That would be how the Shimano levers switch between friction and indexed.